# Убрать форматирование визуальным редактором. {wordpress}

Tags: wordpress

Обыскал все форумы, так и не нашел, как в Wordpress убрать форматирование тегов/стилей при переключение с html кода на визуальный редактор? 
Т.е есть верстка натянутая на Wordpress, хочу редактировать код не через html, а через визуальный редактор, при обновлении страницы редактор съедает часть тегов и стилей...

---

добавлял в `functions.php`, не помогает =/

```js
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('comment_text', 'wpautop'); 
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wptexturize');  
remove_filter('comment_text', 'wptexturize');
```

Comment: А не наводит на мысль что слово "ВИЗУАЛЬНЫЙ"  - это как бэ НЕ для кода, и что для кода есть html? Короче, прекращай хотеть ересь, если хочешь чтобы сайт жил долго и счастливо (в 5м ВП будет Gutenberg - вот обрадуешься)

Comment: да просто отключите визуальный редактор (фильтр `user_can_richedit` в помощь)